# Unable to open files with non-ASCII names with LibreOffice on a tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libreoffice, tablet, mir

When opening a file with a non-ASCII name with LibreOffice Writer (4.4.6.3) through the Desktop Apps Scope (1.3.2.2) there is an error message:

> /home/phablet/shared/memoire.2.odt does not exist.

The actual name of the file is `/home/phablet/Documents/tmp/mémoire.odt`.

In the error message the non-ASCII characters are replaced with '?' if the language of the system does not have these characters, if it has - then it's replaced with a phonetic equivalent even for different alphabets.

Should I look into Libertine (https://bugs.launchpad.net/libertine)?

Comment: Can you rename the file to a conventional name and edit it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, ASCII filenames are fine.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a bug in LibreOffice, as somewhere on the way the filename is being handled by something uncapable of rendering characters in your current locale (so the underlying routines try their best).  I would suggest reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on KDE Plasma on top of Arch Linux where LibreOffice couldn't open files with non-ASCII characters such as umlauts. Okular on the other hand would open and display the same file just fine.

Before launching Plasma with `startx`, the locale was set to `de_AT.UTF-8` according to `locale`.

After launching Plasma, I could see in the regional settings under "Formats" that a different locale was used: `Deutschland - Deutsch(de_DE)`.
Changing that entry to `Österreich - Österreichisches Deutsch (de_AT)` (last quarter of the list) fixed the issue: Now LibreOffice opens those files without a hitch.

I assume that the locales have to match.

---

As a side note: Setting the format to `Default (C)` fixed the problem somewhat: LibreOffice would open the file now but the file's name in the window title was garbled.